# WCF RIA, Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, wcf, mvvm, ria

I am working on a Silverlight 4 project. I am using WCF RIA on the server and expose the model using a DomainService. I have 2 tables, let's say Table1 and Table2 linked with Foreign key say FID.

Therefore, i can Load data from both table 1 and table 2 in single data grid.

But my question is while editing datagrid if i need to change foreign key's Link, let's say row 1 is linked to foreign key FID1 and I want to change that link to FID2. In same time i want change the content of  table 2 in data grid on that row.

Example
datagrid1[ID1 Name Add FID1 F_post F_Name] => [ID1 Name Add FID2 F_post2 F_Name2]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the problem ...

Have you used the automatically generated data source templates?

That should automatically set the linked object as something like a drop down list.